# CodeIgniter session vs cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an application which is under development in CodeIgniter. But I have a problem with session management. By default, sessions in CodeIgniter are saved onto the visitor's machine, which means they last about two hours without being deleted on the close action (visitor closing the browser); while all of us know that PHP keeps session as long as the browser runs, and as it is closed by the user, it will kill it.

My problem: I love CI session style, but for some particular purposes and in some instances I need PHP session style (being deleted when browser is closed). CI provides me such option but I do not like to delete all sessions when the browser is closed. I need only two or three session values to be removed on browser shut down. Should I use go back to PHP pure session for the instances where sessions must be delete on browser shut down? Or CI has some options for customizing the lifespan of session for individual vlaues?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change/set the value of sess_expiration config variable in the file application/config/config.php - the default is 7200 seconds (2 hrs). Set it to zero to never expire. Another useful variable is sess_expire_on_close.  More details at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

If you want to customize across different types of sessions, you can create your own Session class based on CI code, you can create a new class or extend class CI_Session and just make it read from a different set of config variables. 
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/Session.php

Comment: I already know that. What i need is to have session_expire_on_close only on some sessions and not all.

Comment: see the update to the comment, hope this will address your question